# I'm making an app with HTML and I need to make an app icon. How can I implement the icon?

Tags: html, appicon

I'm wondering if it's favicon or meta, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a series of meta tags you need to use depending on whether you are trying to view your app on a web browser or as an app icon within an operating system. Here are the versions I typically include in a web project. They typicallly cover most of my needs, but there are an extensive list of icons you can provide depending on the platform you are targeting.

```
<link
      rel="apple-touch-icon"
      sizes="180x180"
      href="https://yourwebiste.com/images/apple-touch-icon.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="https://yourwebiste.com/images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
      href="https://yourwebiste.com/images/favicon-16x16.png"
    />
```

[image: Table of favicon sizes]